# Cannnot do "gqlgen generate"

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

First, I initialized gqlgen.

```
go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen init
```

Second, I fixed resolver.go and schema.resolvers.go
And, I execute this. Then error has occurred.

```
$ go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate
reloading module info
modelgen: unable to find type: github.com/99designs/gqlgen/interfaces.Int
exit status 1
```

Do you know what is problem?

I did not expect what is problem.

Answer (score 1):

I add this to gqlgen.yml, problem is solved.

```
models:
  ID:
    model:
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.ID
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int32
  Int:
    model:
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64
      - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int32
```